# Dask unable to write to parquet with concatenated data

Tags: pandas, dask, parquet

I am trying to do the following:

Read in a .dat file with pandas, converting it to a dask dataframe, concatenate it to another dask dataframe that I read in from a parquet file, and then output to a new parquet file.  I do the following:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

hist_pth = "\path\to\hist_file"
hist_file = dd.read_parquet(hist_pth)

pth = "\path\to\file"
daily_file = pd.read_csv(pth, sep="|", encoding="latin")
daily_file = daily_file.astype(hist_file.dtypes.to_dict(), errors="ignore")
dask_daily_file = dd.from_pandas(daily_file, npartitions=1)

combined_file = dd.concat([dask_daily_file, hist_file])

output_path = "\path\to\output"
combined_file.to_parquet(output_path)
```

The `combined_file.to_parquet(output_path)` always starts and then stops / or doesn't work correctly. In a jupyter notebook when I do this I get a kernel fail error. When I do it in a python script the script completes but the whole combined file isn't written (I know because of the size - the CSV is 140MB and the parquet file is around 1GB - the output of `to_parquet` is only 20MB).

Some context, this is for an ETL process and with the amount of data were adding daily I'm soon going to run out of memory on the historical and combined datasets, so I'm trying to migrate the process from just pandas to Dask to handle the larger than memory data I will soon have.  The current data, daily + historical, still fits in memory but just barely (I already make use of categoricals, these are stored in the parquet file and then I copy that schema to the new file).

I also noticed that after the `dd.concat([dask_daily_file, hist_file])` that I am unable to call `.compute()` even on simple tasks without it crashing the same way it does when writing to parquet.  For example, on the original, pre-concatenated data, I can call `hist_file["Value"].div(100).compute()` and get the expected value but the same method on combined_file crashes.  Even just `combined_file.compute()` to turn it into a pandas df crashes. I have tried repartitioning as well with no luck.

I was able to do these exact operations, just in pandas, without issue.  But again, I'm going to be running out of memory soon which is why I am moving to dask.

Is this something dask isn't able to handle? If it can handle it, am I processing it correctly? Specifically, it seems like the concat is causing issues.  Any help appreciated!

UPDATE

After playing around more I ended up with the following error:

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'categories'`

There is an existing GitHub issue that seems like it could be related to this - i asked and am waiting for confirm.

As a work around I converted all categorical columns to strings/objects and tried again and then ended up with

`ArrowTypeError: ("Expected a bytes object, got a 'int' object, 'Conversion failed for column Account with type object')`

When I check that column `df["Account"].dtype` it returns `dtype('O')` so I think I have the correct dtype already.  The values in this column are mainly numbers but there are some records with just letters.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: I encourage you to try to create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in Pandas after concatenating dataframes and saving the result to Parquet format..

```
data = pd.concat([df_1, d2, df3], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
data.to_parquet(filename)
```

..apparently because the rows contained different data types, either int or float. By forcing them before saving to have the same data type the error goes away

```
cols = ["first affected col", "second affected col", ..]
data[cols] = data[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)
```